# The same as the category of commutative monoids.

Tags: category-theory

Let $*:*(n)=*$. A map of operads $$*\to End_A$$ gives us for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ a map
$$*\to Set(A^n,A).$$ In particular, $$*\to Set(A^2,A)$$ gives us a selected function $\mu:A^2\to A$. How do I prove that algebras over the operad $*$ in sets are precisely commutative monoids?

Comment: Since you don't specify, my first thought was that you were talking about [planar operads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/planar+operad), but then we get all monoids, not just the commutative ones, so I assume you want [symmetric operads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+operad).

Answer (score 3):

I'll start off by copying my comment, since comments aren't permanent.

Since you don't specify, my first thought was that you were talking about [planar operads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/planar+operad), but then we get all monoids, not just the commutative ones, so I assume you want [symmetric operads](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+operad).

Note that a symmetric operad has an action of $S^n$ in degree $n$, which we can think of as permuting the variables of the $n$-ary operations.

So an operad morphism $*\to \operatorname{End}(A)$ is a choice $\mu_n$ for all $n\ge 0$ of a symmetric function $A^n\to A$ subject to the constraint that all compositions are compatible and $\mu_1$ is necessarily the identity map.

In particular, if we start with a commutative monoid $(A,*,1)$, then define $$\mu_n(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n a_i,$$
this gives a map $*\to \operatorname{End}(A)$.

Conversely, given the maps $\mu_i$,
we have $\mu_2(a,b)=\mu_2(b,a)$ by symmetry. 
Moreover $$\mu_2(a,\mu_0) = \mu_2(\mu_1(a),\mu_0)= \mu_1(a)=a,$$ 
so $\mu_0$ is an identity for $\mu_2$.
Finally
$$\mu_3(a,b,c) = \mu_2(a,\mu_2(b,c)) = \mu_2(\mu_2(a,b),c),$$
so $\mu_2$ is associative. Thus $(A,\mu_2,\mu_0)$ is a commutative monoid.

Comment: how can i be certain that these constructions are inverse to each other?

Comment: @JacobLaurinitus Well certainly the $\mu_2$ we get from a commutative monoid is just the product and $\mu_0$ is the identity, so going from commutative monoid to map of operads and back is the identity. Conversely, you can prove that since compositions in the $*$ operad are unique, the corresponding unique $n$-ary operation $\mu_n$ must be the $n$-fold product by $\mu_2$. Thus going from map to monoid to map again is also the identity.

Comment: What would an algebra morphism look like?

Comment: @JacobLaurinitus An algebra morphism should be a map $f:A\to B$ such that $\mu_{B,n}\circ f^n = f\circ \mu_{A,n}$.